# Должна родить - СГС или осложненное СГС?

Tags: сказуемые

Н.Шапиро на сайте *[Готовимся к экзаменам](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304304)* пишет, что

> в составном глагольном сказуемом (СГС) могут употребляться вспомогательные глаголы двух типов: фазисные и модальные ( со значением возможности, желания и пр.): мочь, хотеть, желать, готовиться, стремиться, решить, уметь, а также  модальное значение могут выражать не только вспомогательные глаголы, но и некоторые краткие прилагательные и причастия, наречия (слова категории состояния), существительные: рад, должен, готов, обязан, способен, вынужден, надо, можно, нельзя, мастер, в состоянии, в силах и пр.
>
> Она не родила, но, по расчету по моему, должна родить.
>
> **должна родить** - СГС.

С другой стороны, [здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_6)
пишут:

> Образец разбора
>
> Я должен уехать сегодня.
>
> **Должен уехать** – ОСЛОЖНЕННОЕ составное глагольное сказуемое. Основная часть уехать выражена субъектным инфинитивом. Вспомогательная часть должен имеет модальное значение и выражено составным именным сказуемым, в котором основная часть должен выражена кратким прилагательным; нулевая связка указывает на настоящее время изъявительного наклонения.

должна родить, должна уехать - это СГС или все же ОСЛОЖНЕННОЕ СГС?

Answer (score 5):

В СГС модальность может выражаться глаголом (мочь, хотеть, решить), а также кратким прилагательным, существительным, фразеологизмом, описательным оборотом с модальным значением (должен, обязан, в в силах, не прочь, состоянии, мастер, любитель) но в этом случае делается приписка: со связкой.

В случае ненулевой связки такие сказуемые иногда рассматриваются как **трехкомпонентные:** готов был уехать.

Примеры осложненных СГС: хотел начать работать, не должен бояться возражать. В этом случае увеличивается число элементов вспомогательной части (фазовых или модальных).

Answer (score 4):

На том же сайте говорится:

Данное сказуемое фактически не является осложнённым. В русском языке, например, нет глаголов с модальным значением долженствования, необходимости, неизбежности и т.п. Эти значения всегда выражаются краткими прилагательными или наречиями. Поэтому составные глагольные сказуемые с таким значением вспомогательной части всегда включают в свой состав составное именное микросказуемое.