# "Он был охотник повеселиться" - тип сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые

> Он был охотник повеселиться.

На [одном сайте сказано](http://www.tutoronline.ru/blog/vidy-skazuemyh-v-russkom-jazyke), что данное предложение содержит составное глагольное сказуемое, но мне кажется, что можно сказать, что это составное именное сказуемое: есть глагол-связка **быть**, есть именная часть: **охотник повеселиться**.

Comment: Схожий вопрос - [должна родить - СГС или осложненное СГС?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417143/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A1%D0%93%D0%A1-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%93%D0%A1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это составное глагольное сказуемое, вспомогательный глагол выражен **модальным существительным.**

Другие варианты: мастер, любитель, охотник.

Comment: Глагол выражен существительным? Чудно. Или ЧуднО. А вот ссылочку бы...

Comment: @Niemand - вот [схожий вопрос](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417143/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A1%D0%93%D0%A1-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%93%D0%A1). Да, это СГС. Осложненное СГС, в котором вспомогательная часть выражена "[составным именным микросказуемым с модальным значением](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_6)".

Comment: Это не тот случай.

Comment: Вера, я не очень вас понял: вы хотите сказать, что мастер, любитель, охотник  - это модальные слова?

Comment: Серж, я, как правило, опасаюсь что-либо говорить от себя и обычно нахожу информацию в каких-либо источниках. У Кустовой в " Синтаксисе современного русского языка"  говорится о модальных существительных.

Comment: Но такие слова, как и модальные наречия, в прошедшем времени имеют связку, например: я был готов ответить.

Comment: Да, я прочитал. Но я впервые встречаю, чтобы такие сущ-е обладали модальностью. Я обратился на Грамму, посмотрим, что они ответят.

Comment: Да, интересно, расскажете потом.