# Какой тип сказуемого? [1]

Tags: синтаксис, тип-сказуемого

> Я был мастером комбинировать.

*Был* -- связка, *мастером* -- вспомогательный компонент, *комбинировать* -- смысловой глагол, то есть составное глагольное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это **составное глагольное сказуемое**, модальная связка ― "был мастером".

Мастер, охотник, любитель ― эти модальные существительные  имеют связку БЫТЬ для выражения грамматических значений, свойственных глаголу, так как не могут выразить эти грамматические значения сами.

Comment: А почему *был* входит в связку?

Answer (score 3):

Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался на сайте[“Он был охотник повеселиться” - тип сказуемого?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417294/%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)
А вот что пишет **Грамма.ру.**

Сказуемое в предложении **“Он был охотник повеселиться”** лучше всего отнести *к составному глагольному,* так как сочетание "был охотник" в данном случае выполняет функцию модального компонента **(=любил).** Аналогична   структура "был мастер (+ инфинитив)" (=умел).В научной литературе, относящейся к середине ХХ века, встречается трактовка таких структур как составного именного сказуемого (например, в академический Грамматике русского языка 1952-1954 годов).